# Pasar parametros al Constructor o a un metodo

Tags: java

Mi duda es la siguiente, deberia pasar los parametros obtenidos de un JTextField a los metodos setter de la clase Usuario? o pasarlos directamente al constructor de la clase Usuario, cual seria la diferencia?

```
//Esta es la clase registro pero resumida//

 public class Registro extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private JTextField campoNombre,campoApellido,campoCorreo,campoNombreUsuario;
private JPasswordField campoContrasena;
private JRadioButton masculino,femenino;
private ButtonGroup grupo;
private JButton finalizar,limpiar;


public Registro(){

    super("Registro OO");
    Toolkit posicionMonitor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension tamanio = posicionMonitor.getScreenSize();
    int anchoVentana = tamanio.width;
    int altoVentana = tamanio.height;
    setBounds(((anchoVentana/2)-(400/2)),((altoVentana/2)-(500/2)),400,500);
    this.setResizable(false);

    iniciarComponentes();
}

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(e.getSource().equals(limpiar)){
        limpiaCampos();
    }

    else if(e.getSource().equals(finalizar)){
        tomaDatos();
    }
}
public void tomaDatos(){
    String sex ="";
    if(masculino.isSelected())
        sex = "Masculino";
    else
        sex = "Femenino";

    Usuario nuevoUsuario = new Usuario(campoNombre.getText(),campoApellido.getText(),campoNombreUsuario.getText(),
            campoCorreo.getText(),sex,campoContrasena.getPassword());

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro Exitoso","Registrado",JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);

    limpiaCampos();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mi personalmente no me gusta tener constructores con muchos parámetros porque:

1. Complica la lectura y comprensión del código.
2. Añade complejidad a la herencia que normalmente no es útil.

Por tanto, creo que sería más conveniente inicializar cada usuario con unos parámetros "mandatory" (por ejemplo su nombre de usuario y contraseña) para asegurar la **consistencia de cada objeto** y dejar el resto de datos como algo opcional manejable con setters. El código resultaría mucho más legible. Sería algo parecido a esto:

```
String nombreUsuario = campoNombreUsuario.getText();  
String pass = campoContrasena.getPassword();

Usuario nuevoUsuario = new Usuario(nombreUsuario, pass);

nuevoUsuario.setNombre(campoNombre.getText());
nuevoUsuario.setApellido(campoApellido.getText());
nuevoUsuario.setCorreo(campoCorreo.getText());
```

Supongo que es un tema más de estilo y/o orden en el código. Hay manuales de estilo que prohíben expresamente el uso de constructores con más de 3 parámetros... y en otros casos se anima a que los constructores estén muy parametrizados para "aliviar" código intrascendente.

Lo importante es mantener la reusabilidad, claridad, concisión, principio de responsabilidad única... y todos esas buenas prácticas que enuncia la ingeniería del software tradicional.

De todas formas existen muchas formas más o menos correctas de hacerlo, pudiéndose utilizar más de una a la vez. Por ejemplo, usando varios constructores, y dejando setters para los atributos.

Comment: Consulta amigo, creo que tu respuesta es completa y valida. Pero hago referencia a "Lo importante es mantener la reusabilidad, claridad, concisión" hacer la construccion de un objeto, con solo set de cada propiedad, no ensuciaría el codigo?, seria mas largo y engorroso? es una pregunta!

Comment: Si, es cierto que muchos setters, a veces, son un poco pesados, porque se tarda más en escribir el código e incluso a veces puedes caer en antipatrones, dejando objetos inconsistentes o con funcionalidad reducida. 

En todo caso, es responsabilidad del programador tener cuidado de estas cosas (los puristas de la IS pueden no estar de acuerdo en esto), y creo que, siempre es preferible dejar el código lo más legible posible, tanto para ti (revisiones futuras) como para otros compañeros que deban trabajar sobre el código. 
Saludos !

Comment: Saludos! y gracias por el aporte nunca me lo habia preguntado jajaja

Answer (score 0):

Depende la implementación que estás haciendo de tu clase, si efectivamente requieres que sea un campo base de tu clase, debes enviarlo por el constructor.

Puedes sobrecargar el constructor de la clase si lo deseas y dejar ambos, ya que el lenguaje lo permite y te da mas libertades a la hora de continuar con el desarrollo.